# How to annotate a class descriptor

Tags: typescript

How do I correctly annotate the following:

```
export class TestCls {
    static SomeStaticFn(): TestCls {
        // Do some stuff...

        // Return the class descriptor to allow a "fluid usage" of SomeStaticFn
        return TestCls;
    }
}

// TS error TS2339: Property 'SomeStaticFn' does not exist on type 'TestCls'.
TestCls.SomeStaticFn().SomeStaticFn();
```

I do understand the error since the return type `TestCls` annotates the class "itself" and not its descriptor but I don't know how to correctly annotate this...

*Ps.:* I'm not 100% sure about the correct terminology here (class "itself", descriptor etc.) and would really appreciate some corrections here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may sound a little weird at first, but the reason TypeScript throws is signature of your static function. I hope the following is reasonable:

If you use the name of a class (`TestCls`) to specify the return value of a function, the function is expected to return an *instance*  of that class. Not the constructor (=its definition is how you called it). This means, writing something like `foo():MyClass`, TypeScript expects `foo()` to return a new *instance* of `MyClass`, not the class itself.

Also, defining a function signature like this, TypeScript will try to assert that the return type you gave it, will be correct. So `:MyClass` is actually *type assertion*. Which means you are overwriting the return type that is infered by TypeScript.

The weird part is that if you write something like this:

```
function hello (): string {
  return 5;
}
```

TypeScript will tell you that `Type '5' is not assignable to type 'string'`. I guess TypeScript can not really differentiate that the class and its instance is something different. At the end of the day, they're both `object`s.

**tl;dr;** Remove the return type assertion from your static function and everything will be fine. TypeScript is smart enough to infer the return type anyway.

```
export class TestCls {
    static SomeStaticFn() {
        // Do some stuff...

        // Return the class descriptor to allow a "fluid usage" of SomeStaticFn
        return TestCls;
    }
}

TestCls.SomeStaticFn().SomeStaticFn();
```

Comment: I just realized that it's also possible to explicitly annotate the return type using the signature `static SomeStaticFn(): typeof TestCls`

Comment: Yes, this also should references the constructor function not the instance :)